# Remove duplicate child lists from a parent list ignoring the order

Tags: c#, linq

I have a structure similar to this

```
Parent List {ChildList1, ChildList2, ChildList3, ChildList4}
ChildList1: { "B1", "B2", "B3" }
ChildList2: { "B1", "B3", "B2" }
ChildList3: { "B1", "B2" }
ChildList4: { "B5", "B3", "B2", "B4" }
```

Now I want to remove the child lists that have similar (equal) values and keep only one copy of them in the Parent List.

```
New Parent List {ChildList1, ChildList3, ChildList4}
```

I prefer to use Distinct, I wanted to know if I can use it for List<> too?

```
List<List<string>> ParentList = new List<List<string>>();


List<string> ChildList1 = new List<string> { "B1", "B2", "B3" };
List<string> ChildList2 = new List<string> { "B1", "B3", "B2" };
List<string> ChildList3 = new List<string> { "B1", "B2" };
List<string> ChildList4 = new List<string> { "B5", "B3", "B2", "B4" };

ParentList.Add(ChildList1);
ParentList.Add(ChildList2);
ParentList.Add(ChildList3);
ParentList.Add(ChildList4);


var NewParentList = ParentList.Distinct();
// Display results.
```

`ChildList1` and `ChildList2` are considered equal and only one needs to be kept. So the order doesn't matter.

Comment: @BasBrekelmans I have included the Lists in the question. It is obvious.

Comment: @Vahid: what's obvious? You have shown some lists but you have not mentioned which list(s) you want to keep. When is a list a duplicate, if one item matches, two, three, all..? Does the order matter etc...

Comment: Do you want to remove {B1, B2} because {B1, B2, B3} already exists? Or do you want to remove {B2, B3, B1} because ordering doesn't matter? Be more specific, it is not obvious.

Comment: @TimSchmelter For example ChildList1 and ChildList2 are considered equal and only one needs to be kept.

Comment: @BasBrekelmans I want to keep {B1, B2} because I don't have another child list that is like {B2, B1} or {B1, B2} but I want to remove {B1,B3, B2} cause there is already another list containing {B1, B2, B3}

Comment: The red arrows are ridiculous :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this could help:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<List<string>> ParentList = new List<List<string>>();


        List<string> ChildList1 = new List<string> { "B1", "B2", "B3" };
        List<string> ChildList2 = new List<string> { "B1", "B3", "B2" };
        List<string> ChildList3 = new List<string> { "B1", "B2" };
        List<string> ChildList4 = new List<string> { "B5", "B3", "B2", "B4" };

        ParentList.Add(ChildList1);
        ParentList.Add(ChildList2);
        ParentList.Add(ChildList3);
        ParentList.Add(ChildList4);

        var result = ParentList.Distinct(new Comparer()).ToList();
    }
}

internal class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<List<string>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<string> list1, List<string> list2)
    {
        return list1.All(x => list2.Contains(x)) && list2.All(x => list1.Contains(x));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<string> obj)
    {
        return obj.Count;
    }
}
```

of course you must use better algorithm for generating hash codes. it will remove childList1 or childList2, but there is no guaranty that which one is removed.

Comment: _" there is no guaranty that which one is removed"_ For LINQ-To-Objects the order is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `Distinct` you could implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>` to find duplicates according to the strings ignoring the order, for example:

```
public class IgnoreSequenceOrderComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;
        return x.OrderBy(str => str).OrderBy(str => str)
            .SequenceEqual(y.OrderBy(str => str).OrderBy(str => str));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> seq)
    {
        if (seq == null) return int.MinValue;
        int hash = 0;
        unchecked
        {
            var strings = seq.OrderBy(str => str);
            foreach (T obj in strings)
                hash = 17 * hash + obj.GetHashCode();
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Now this code removed the duplicates:

```
var NewParentList = ParentList.Distinct(new IgnoreSequenceOrderComparer<string>());
```